# How to fix "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0" error while creating simple ChatBot in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot

I am creating simple ChatBot for the first time and stuck with error "xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0"

I have already solved pip, tensorflow, fetching url, ssl certificate, no module name chatterbot, no module name chatterbot-corpus issues

```py
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
import os

bot = ChatBot('Bot')
bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

for files in os.listdir('D:/aaprojects/Chat bot 2019\chatterbot-corpus-1.2.0\chatterbot-corpus-1.2.0\chatterbot_corpus\data\english/'):
        data = open ('D:/aaprojects/Chat bot 2019\chatterbot-corpus-1.2.0\chatterbot-corpus-1.2.0\chatterbot_corpus\data\english/' + files, 'r').readlines()
        bot.train(data)

while True:
        message = input('You:')
        if message.strip() != 'Bye':
                reply = bot.get_response(message)
                print('ChatBot:',reply)

        if message.strip()=='Bye':
                print('ChatBot:Bye')
                break
```

Error Message:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0" i believe when its gone my ChatBot wold run
```

Comment: Please include the XML file content as well, since the error indicates that it is malformed and can't be parsed

Comment: i tried but did not worked.....could you please copy paste those lines of code (XML file content)

Comment: By XML file content, I mean the files you are using to train the bot. Those inside `D:/aaprojects/Chat bot 2019\chatterbot-corpus-1.2.0\chatterbot-corpus-1.2.0\chatterbot_corpus\data\english/`, as per your code. You don't need to paste the entire contents for all files, just post the file that causes your error. You can find that by printing the value of `files` before opening and calling `bot.train()`.